# How to test focus in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Consider the following `skFocus` service:

```
angular.module('sk.focus', []).service('skFocus', function($timeout) {
  return function(cssSelector) {
    $timeout(function() {
      var element = document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);

      if (element.length > 0) {
        element[0].focus();
      }
    }, 100);
  };
});
```

I'm trying to create a test for this service:

```
describe('Service: skFocus', function() {
  beforeEach(module('sk.focus'));

  var $window, $timeout, skFocus;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$window_, _$timeout_, _skFocus_) {
    $window = _$window_;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    skFocus = _skFocus_;

    angular.element(document.body).append('<input id="my-input-field" type="text">');
  }));

  it('Should set focus', function() {
    skFocus('#my-input-field');
    $timeout.flush();

    var $inputElement = $window.jQuery('#my-input-field');

    console.log($inputElement.length);   // 1

    expect($inputElement.is(':focus')).toBe(true);   // Fails!!
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, the test fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: suggest you append first before compile since i doubt you can focus an element that isn't in the DOM

Comment: Actually, I don't really need to compile. I updated the code in the question. The issue still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past I wrote similar tests using [document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement) to verify that an element received focus.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue with `focus` not being triggered. In my case problem was that I created `HTML` template in memory `const template = angular.element('<div><input type="text"></div>')` and didn't append it to `document.body`.

After appending `template` to the `<body>` the `focus` listener started to work.