# AngularJS: how to test directive which gives focus to element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

**Note: the suggested link is an answer to a question about a service, and doesn't give a clear explanation on how to solve this issue**

I'm trying to setup a karma test for my simple (and working) AngularJS `autofocus` directive:

```
app.directive('autofocus', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    replace: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      scope.$watch(attr.autofocus,
        function (value) {
          if (value) {
            $timeout(function () {
              element[0].focus();
              console.log('focus called');
            });
          }
        }
      );
    }
  };
});
```

This is my current test:

```
describe('The autofocus directive', function () {
  var timeout;
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function($timeout) {
    timeout = $timeout;
  }));

  it('should set focus to first autofocus element', function () {
    var form = angular.element('<form />');
    var input1 = angular.element('<input type="text" name="first" />');
    var input2 = angular.element('<input type="text" name="second" autofocus="true" />');
    form.append(input1);
    form.append(input2);
    spyOn(input2[0], 'focus');
    timeout.flush();
    expect(input2[0].focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

This is the (FAILED) output from `karma`:

> *$ node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js*
>   INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.23 server started at http:// localhost:8080/
>   INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
>   INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux)]: Connected on socket U34UATs8jZDPB74AXpqR with id 96802943
>   PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux): Executed 0 of 20 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
>   PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) The autofocus directive should set focus to first autofocus element FAILED
>               **Expected spy focus to have been called.**
>   PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux): Executed 20 of 20 (1 FAILED) (0.156 secs / 0.146 secs)

---

Just adding

```
input[0].focus();
```

after `spyOn(input[0], 'focus')` the test succeeds, of course, but it's not what I want...

---

The final question is: ***How do I karma-test a directive which sets focus to an element ?***

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test focus in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196072/how-to-test-focus-in-angularjs)

Comment: That question is for a service, and the answer is not so clear, for me... :-(

Comment: Throw this up into a jsfiddle? Easier to work with if we can see it failing.

Comment: Of course: this is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ksqhmkqm/ (though it's my first jasmine fiddle, I don't know if it's ok... :-).

Comment: I have updated the fiddle and now it will pass. Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ksqhmkqm/1/. Reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330098/how-do-i-check-if-my-element-has-been-focussed-in-a-unit-test

Comment: @themyth92, you should be named themyth2014... :-) Your comment is resolutive (my bad... :-), if you want to post it as an answer I'll be happy to accept it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call angular.element only in unit test, Angular will not understand the "autofocus" is a directive. Therefore, in your code :

```
var form = angular.element('<form />');
var input1 = angular.element('<input type="text" name="first" />');
var input2 = angular.element('<input type="text" name="second" autofocus="true" />');
form.append(input1);
form.append(input2);
```

Angular will not set autofocus as a directive and will not assign anythings relating to the "autofocus" directive that you have already declared. 
In order to do this in unit test, you have to use **$compile** to assign it with a scope. 
You can change the fiddle to like this to pass the test:

http://jsfiddle.net/ksqhmkqm/1/.

**As you can see, I have created a new scope**

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
```

**And create a new template**

```
element = angular.element('<form><input type="text" name="first" /><input type="text" name="second" autofocus="true" /></form>');
```

**And assign the created scope to this new template**

```
$compile(element)(scope);
scope.$digest();
```

With this way, angular will understand the "autofocus" is a directive and assign all the event that you have created to this element that "autofocus" is working on.

The testing for the focus event I have followed this reference:

[How do I check if my element has been focussed in a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330098/how-do-i-check-if-my-element-has-been-focussed-in-a-unit-test)